# convert yyyyqq to pandas date in clean way

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert year and quarter to date in `pandas`. In example below I am trying to get `1980-03-31` for `1980Q1` and so on.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'year':['1980','1980','1980','1980'],'qtr':
                 ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']})

scenario['date']=pd.to_datetime(scenario['year']+scenario['qtr'], infer_datetime_format=True)
scenario[['date','year','qtr']]
      date      year    qtr
0   1980-01-01  1980    Q1
1   1980-04-01  1980    Q2
2   1980-07-01  1980    Q3
3   1980-10-01  1980    Q4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for `QuarterEnd` offset?

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'year':['1980','1980','1980','1980'],'qtr':
                 ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year']+df['qtr']) + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()

df[['date','year','qtr']]
        date  year qtr
0 1980-03-31  1980  Q1
1 1980-06-30  1980  Q2
2 1980-09-30  1980  Q3
3 1980-12-31  1980  Q4
```

Comment: that would be one way to do which is good. But is there any argument that can be passed inside to_datetime function itself?

Comment: @itthrill not that I know of, or one that's specified in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). You might check out the source code if you really want to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.PeriodIndex(df['year'] + df['qtr'], freq='Q').to_timestamp(freq='Q')
```

output:

```
0   1980-03-31
1   1980-06-30
2   1980-09-30
3   1980-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd


def func(x):
    # converts columns to datetime.date object
    if x.qtr == 'Q1':
        month = 1
    elif x.qtr == 'Q2':
        month = 3
    elif x.qtr == 'Q3':
        month = 7
    elif x.qtr == 'Q4':
        month = 10
    dt_obj = dt.date(year=int(x.year), month=month, day=1)
    return dt_obj


df=pd.DataFrame({'year':['1980','1980','1980','1980'],'qtr':
                 ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']})
print(df)
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
print(df)
```